# Is there a problem with the javadoc for MethodHandles#exactInvoker?

Tags: java, methodhandle

I'm trying to understand the [`exactInvoker` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#exactInvoker(java.lang.invoke.MethodType)).

It reads, in part:

> For example, to emulate an `invokeExact` call to a variable method handle `M`, extract its type `T`, look up the invoker method `X` for `T`, and call the invoker method, as `X.invoke(T, A...)`.

Everything makes sense except for the `X.invoke(T, A...)` bit.

Shouldn't this be `X.invoke(M, A...)`, where `M` is the leading `MethodHandle` being adapted (and `A...` represents its arguments)?

Comment: Yes. Looks like a typo